# In Flink, how to write DataStream to single file?

Tags: scala, apache-flink

The `writeAsText` or `writeAsCsv` methods of a `DataStream` write as many files as worker threads. As far as I could see, the methods only let you specify the path to these files and some formatting.

For debugging and testing purposes, it would be really useful to be able to print everything to a single file, without having to change the set up to having a single worker thread.

Is there any non-overly-complicated way to achieve this? I suspect it should be possible implementing a custom `SinkFunction`, but not sure about that one (besides, it also feels like a hassle for something that seems relatively simple).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can achieve this by setting the parallelism to 1. This way, the writing happens only on one machine.

```
writeAsText(path).setParallelism(1);
```

Comment: deprecated in newer versions. Refer to SteamingFileSink

Comment: Good answer but I will not upvote since is deprecated and @eseuteo answer is the up to date one

Answer (score 4):

In Flink 1.13 this is not done with writeAsText function anymore, as it's deprecated.

As can be seen [here](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/api/java/index.html?deprecated-list.html) now StreamingFileSink class and addSink operation should be used. Regarding setting the parallelism to 1, this is also done differently (by setting the StreamExecutionEnvironment parallelism to 1, with setParallelism method)

```
val env: StreamExecutionEnvironment = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment
env.setParallelism(1)

val sink: StreamingFileSink[String] = StreamingFileSink
  .forRowFormat(new Path(outPath), new SimpleStringEncoder[String]("UTF-8"))
  .build()

dataStream.map(_.toString).addSink(sink)
```

Comment: `StreamingFileSink`  is deprecated in the newer version, use `org.apache.flink.connector.file.sink.FileSink` instead